# Ireport 4.7 design to calculate page wise total amount

Tags: jasper-reports

I want to calculate the total amounts in each page and should be display in Grand total amount(Page total amount).  I create local varaible grand total in this variable properties  i choose SF{col3} text fields. Calculation - > sum, Reset type - > none , variable expression - > new BigDecimal{SF(col3)}, Intial Value Expression -> new BigDecimal("0"). I track that variable into jasper report and i choose Evalution time - > auto. After execution it showing wrong answer. Kindly any one to answer this problem.

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: Group wise total is working fine. But what i am trying to ask you is  i want to sum the group wise total and it should be printed as grand total.At each group wise total is over i  pass this value into main report using sub report variable and destination variable. Each page group wise iteration the group wise total amount return into main report. On that main i paste that same variable what i used in sub report. On that variable properties i changed reset type-> Page and Increment type - > group .

Comment: calculation -> sum but its working good when the group wise item record finished in one page. But if any group wise record having more records it that records goes next page on this scenario the page total is calculated on before group wise records value(group wise total calculated in other page). But not take the balance records total value please any one answer this problem.

Answer (score 0):

The mistake is here is in the Reset type you chose

"Reset type - > none"

Changes the Reset type of the variable to **Page**

Now this will update the total per page.

Hopes that this helps

Thanks.